# Select Item from a ListView and put it into another listView

Tags: android, listview

The problems is: I have a listview_products, for instance, and I have to select one of them per time and put it into another listview_sales, the listview_sales is going to hold all the products that I've been choosing for then make the proccess of sale completely. How could I achieve this behavior? Could you lend me a hand with this please!

Comment: I think you should take a look at [ask] and reformat your question to help us understanding your problem :) Show us what you tried.

Comment: thanks a lot! I'm going to read it right now!

Comment: Just add the selected items to another array and pass it to the adapter that will draw your second listView.

Comment: @Nanoc do you have an example that I could follow? I will appreciate it for sure! thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an ArrayList with object from where your first adapter gets data to draw.

Then you will need another arrayList with the objects of the first that will be drawn on the second ListView.

So, if you implement a OnItemClickListener in your first arraylist to get the selected items.

This is just a pseudocode example.

```
void OnItemClicked(int position) //This is not the real method definition
{
    secondArray.put(firstArray.get(position));
}
```

Then when you want to show that second List just pass that data to its adapter

```
secondListView.setAdapter(new SecondAdapter(secondArray));
```

Hope this helps.